# How to prove $|\sin(a)|+|\cos(a+b)|-|\cos(b)|\geq0$

Tags: inequality

Prove $$|\sin(a)|+|\cos(a+b)|-|\cos(b)|\geq0$$
I want to use this as a lemma, but I dont know how to prove it.

Comment: $$cos(a+b) = cos(a)cos(b) - sin(a)sin(b)$$

Answer (score 3):

We have
$$\eqalign{|\cos(a-c)|
  &=|\cos a\cos c+\sin a\sin c|\cr
  &\le|\cos a|\,|\cos c|+|\sin a|\,|\sin c|\cr
  &\le|\cos c|+|\sin a|\ .\cr}$$
Now substitute $c=a+b$.